# Hangouts api is not working on Ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am using the following code in Ionic app to get the start-hangouts button on Android device.

```
   <!-- In index.html-->  
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
     <!-- In App home page-->
    <div class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout"></div>
```

It's working fine on web browser, but nothing is visible on actual device.